# Fill background color of a circle over time with CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a JS script that runs on setInterval and the scripts progress is stored in a progressPercentage variable. I'm using this percentage value to modify with width of a child div that has a bgcolor. So as it gets wider it starts to fill up more of the parent div.

It's very simple using a square shape, but I'm having a hard time filling in a circle shape `(border-radius: 100%)`.

Right now I'm using 2 divs, and I know there are better ways of doing it, but for now this is what it looks like:

```
<div id="load-bar-frame">
  <div id="load-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#load-bar-frame {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#load-bar {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The JS fills in the background by increasing the width of `#load-bar` so as it's width increases it fills up the `#load-bar-frame` div.

The problem is that in child div's width will start at 0 so its a really skewered circle and doesn't fit inside the parent div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chirpizard/6saxtnen/)

So I'm looking for a better way of filling in the bgcolor.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @alirezasafian Added fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Chirpizard/6saxtnen/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```js
var per = 0;
setInterval(function(){ 
per++;
if(per <= 100){
    $('#load-bar').css({background: "linear-gradient(to right, #000000 "+per+"%,transparent "+per+"%,transparent 100%)"});
   
}

}, 100);
```

```css
#load-bar-frame {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#load-bar {
  width: 100%; /* in this case 20% would be the current progress */
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-bar-frame">
  <div id="load-bar"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6saxtnen/2/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var per = 1;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(changeSize, 100);
});

function changeSize(){
 per++;
    if(per <= 100){
     $("#load-bar").width(per + "%");
        $("#load-bar").height(per + "%");
        $("#load-bar").css("top" , (50 - (per / 2)) + "%");
         $("#load-bar").css("left" , (50 - (per / 2)) + "%")
    }
}
```

```css
#load-bar-frame {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#load-bar {
  background: #000;
  width: 20%; /* in this case 20% would be the current progress */
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 100%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-bar-frame">
  <div id="load-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, this might work. I will need to modify it to fill from bottom to top. I'm going to see if there are some other solutions posted though. Thanks!

Comment: I have added another ans with sliding

Answer (score 1):

```js
var per = 1;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(changeSize, 100);
});

function changeSize(){
 per++;
    if(per <= 100){
     $("#load-bar").width(per + "%");

    }
}
```

```css
#load-bar-frame {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top 20px;
  left: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#load-bar {
  background: #000;
  width: 20%; /* in this case 20% would be the current progress */
  height: 100%;
 
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-bar-frame">
  <div id="load-bar"></div>
</div>
```